# Get frequency of tokens by group in large pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DF which contains a tokenized list of a comment on Reddit. I want to group by the column 'subreddit' and get a list of the most frequently used tokens in the 'tokenized_text' column.  Here is what the data looks like:

```
list(df['tokenized_text'].groupby(df['subreddit']))[25:30]
```

Produces this output:

```
[('15SecondStories',
  745124     [honestly, happened, write, fucking, complaint...
  997789                    [im, sorry, man, first, one, sure]
  1013206                       [little, bit, stupid, deadass]
  1177475                                                [lol]
  1179558    [native, spanish, speaker, school, taught, muc...
  1184372                     [format, incorrect, please, fix]
  1396579    [read, rules, posting, along, announcements, p...
  1859785                                                [lol]
  Name: tokenized_text, dtype: object),
 ('181920', 360480    [pretty, great, body]
  Name: tokenized_text, dtype: object),
 ('182637777', 1628100               [username, created, months, christmas]
  1632561    [approximate, value, mass, ratio, real, value,...
  1634853                                               [http]
  1665160                                           [hiw, whi]
  Name: tokenized_text, dtype: object),
```

I want to aggregate by subreddit and get a frequency dictionary of the most common words for that subreddit.  I want the resulting output to be a pandas df with one column as the subreddit name, and the other column a dictionary of most frequent words (like something produced from FreqDict).

I've tried `df['tokenized_text'].groupby(df['subreddit'].progress_apply(lambda x: nltk.FreqDist(y) for y in x)` but can't quite get it to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think I see the nature of your data. Just in case, could you post the first few lines of `df` itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `df` is structured the way I think it is, this should get you most of the way:

```
df.groupby('subreddit').agg(lambda x: nltk.FreqDist([w for wordlist in x for w in wordlist]))
```

#### Runnable Example with Simulated Data

```
# Simulated data
df = pd.DataFrame({'subreddit': ['news', 'news', 'art'],
                   'tokenized_text': [['some', 'ex', 'words', 'ex'],
                                      ['news', 'news', 'and', 'more', 'news'],
                                      ['draw', 'paint', 'up', 'up', 'down']]})
df
  subreddit                 tokenized_text
0      news          [some, ex, words, ex]
1      news  [news, news, and, more, news]
2       art    [draw, paint, up, up, down]


# Get pandas to print wider-than-usual columns, up to 800px
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 800)

# Group by subreddit and aggregate lists (this likely does not scale well to larger data)
df.groupby('subreddit').agg(lambda x: nltk.FreqDist([w for wordlist in x for w in wordlist]))
                                                             tokenized_text
subreddit
art                             {'draw': 1, 'paint': 1, 'up': 2, 'down': 1}
news       {'some': 1, 'ex': 2, 'words': 1, 'news': 3, 'and': 1, 'more': 1}
```

#### Expanding the dictionaries into DataFrame columns

```
df2 = df.groupby('subreddit').agg(lambda x: nltk.FreqDist([w for wordlist in x for w in wordlist]))

# Method 1: repeated use of the pd.Series() constructor

df2['tokenized_text'].apply(pd.Series).fillna(0).astype(int)
           and  down  draw  ex  more  news  paint  some  up  words
subreddit
art          0     1     1   0     0     0      1     0   2      0
news         1     0     0   2     1     3      0     1   0      1

# Method 2: pd.DataFrame() + df[col].tolist()

pd.DataFrame(df2['tokenized_text'].tolist(), index=df2.index).fillna(0).astype(int)
           and  down  draw  ex  more  news  paint  some  up  words
subreddit
art          0     1     1   0     0     0      1     0   2      0
news         1     0     0   2     1     3      0     1   0      1
```

Comment: This is perfect!  Do you know how to turn the 'subreddit' column into a real column in a pandas df?  I'm not sure how it is functioning now but if you go label(df), only "tokenized_text" will appear as a valid column

Comment: Also, do you know what the appropriate solution is for larger data sets?

Comment: I've edited in two methods to expand the column of dictionaries into DataFrame columns. Unfortunately, I'm not the best person to ask about speeding up this approach for much larger datasets...