# Most Frequent Words from Sentences grouped by category

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to group the 10 most frequent words by category. I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29903025/count-most-frequent-100-words-from-sentences-in-dataframe-pandas) answer already, but I can't quite modify that to get the output I desire.

```
category | sentence
  A           cat runs over big dog
  A           dog runs over big cat
  B           random sentences include words
  C           including this one
```

Output desired:

```
category | word/frequency
   A           runs, 2
               cat: 2
               dog: 2
               over: 2
               big: 2
   B           random: 1
   C           including: 1
```

Since my dataframe is quite large I'd like to only get the top 10 most recurring words. I've also seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49371236/get-frequency-of-tokens-by-group-in-large-pandas-df)

```
df.groupby('subreddit').agg(lambda x: nltk.FreqDist([w for wordlist in x for w in wordlist]))
```

but this method returns counts of letters as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can join the rows and apply the FreqDist after tokenizing the sentence

```
df.groupby('category')['sentence'].apply(lambda x: nltk.FreqDist(nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(' '.join(x))))
```

Out:

```
category           
a         big          2.0
          cat          2.0
          dog          2.0
          over         2.0
          runs         2.0
c         include      1.0
          random       1.0
          sentences    1.0
          words        1.0
d         including    1.0
          one          1.0
          this         1.0
Name: sentence, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 7):

Should you want filter by frequency of the most occurring words the following line will do (2 most frequently occurring words for each category, in this case):

```
from collections import Counter

df.groupby("category")["sentence"].apply(lambda x: Counter(" ".join(x).split()).most_common(2))

category
A            [(cat, 2), (runs, 2)]
B    [(random, 1), (sentences, 1)]
C      [(including, 1), (this, 1)]
Name: sentence, dtype: object
```

Performance wise:

```
%timeit df.groupby("category")["sentence"].apply(lambda x: Counter(" ".join(x).split()).most_common(2))
2.07 ms ± 87.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df.groupby('category')['sentence'].apply(lambda x: nltk.FreqDist(nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(' '.join(x))))
4.96 ms ± 17.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: thanks! i'll play around more to get it in the format i want but this is a great start

Answer (score 1):

```
# Split the sentence into Series    
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.sentence.str.split(' ').tolist())

# Add category with as not been adding with the split
df1['category']  = df['category']

# Melt the Series corresponding to the splited sentence
df1 = pd.melt(df1, id_vars='category', value_vars=df1.columns[:-1].tolist())

# Groupby and count (reset_index will create a column nammed 0)
df1 = df1.groupby(['category', 'value']).size().reset_index()

# Keep the 10 largests numbers 
df1 = df1.nlargest(10, 0)
```

Comment: This is close - for my final output I'm trying to achieve something more like      df1.groupby('category')[0].value_counts()